# How can I create a usable, base class that inherits CCLayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am wanting to create a base class that inherits from `CCLayer`.  My reason is because I have a single-image, full screen `CCSprite` that I want to overlay on every scene of my application.  Creating a base class, and adding a `CCSprite` containing the image as the top-most Z object seems to make sense because it will prevent me from having to re-code the same overlay implementation again and again for each scene.

I've been able to derive a class from `CCLayer` with relative ease.  However, I cannot figure out how to correctly create <strike>a scene</strike> another layer class that is a child, of a child of `CCLayer`.  How can this be done, and work?

I understand that when most users ask such questions, the first follow is "Show us your code."   I can show you the code but I am most interested in is a very generic implementation of Cocos2d object, that is derived from `CClayer` and can be used as a base class for other layers, pre-wiring common sprites and objects.

Comment: subclass CCScene which always adds your custom Cclayer as the last child. Otherwise you'll have to add you custom layer to every scene manually.

Comment: LearnCocos2D: Is there a chance that I could get you to post an answer with a snippet of code that is doing what you are mentioning?  I'm sure this is the answer and I'd like to give you the credit for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be your problem:

> "*I cannot figure out how to create a scene that is a child, of a child of CCLayer.*"

As I understand it, Cocos layers are added as children to Cocos scenes, not the other way around, as the quote seems to imply.

I think you could simply make a custom layer class, deriving it from CCLayer and adding your CCSprite. Then simply go to everywhere you are creating or deriving a CCLayer and instead create or derive it from your custom layer class and then show or hide the sprite when needed.

Alternatively, and probably more easily, you could create a category on CCLayer adding a "showFullscreenSprite" method which simply creates the sprite and sets its image, then calls

```
[self addChild:yourSprite z:yourSprite.zOrder tag:9999];
```

You would also need a corresponding "hideFullscreenSprite" method which would simply do this

```
[self removeChildByTag:9999 cleanup:YES];
```

The nice thing about this approach is you wouldn't need to sub-class at all and all of your CCLayers would now have your "showFullscreenSprite" and "hideFullscreenSprite" methods available.

(Note: "9999" has to be some number you're not already using as a CCNode tag. Make it big enough so you don't have to worry about it. Maybe pull it out into a constant such as "FULL_SCREEN_SPRITE_TAG" or some such for readability.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I had considered the category option but wanted to avoid it since it still involved adding repeated code calls for each new CCLayer that I create. FYI, I updated my questions.  I made a terminology mistake which you quoted. My Class hierarchy that I am trying to create is CCLayer->MyBase_CCLayer->Derived_CCLayer. Part of my problem could be the way that I get a scene and push it on the director stack.  I have a static Scene method in each CCLayer, which is nothing more than what's in the example code. I don't know if I need to do this differently under my circumstance.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to ask a different question.  Your response answers this one, so I'm going to give you the answer mark.  I've found a few other discussions this morning that seem to be pointing me to the problem, but I can't find a solution to it.  Thank you.